# Display current date as default in html/php form when window loads

Tags: javascript, php, html, date

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Smart Hotel - Check In Report</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xxxxindex.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xxxxform.css"/>
<script>
window.onload = function()
{
defaultDate();
}
function defaultDate()
{
var today = new Date();
document.getElementById("displayDate").value = [today.getDate(), today.getMonth()+1,  .getFullYear()].join('/');}
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<div id="screen"> 
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="roundContainer" id="menuBar">
<?php include("./menu.php")?>
</div> <!-- topContainer -->
<div class="roundContainer" id="main">
<form action="" method="Post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to display Check Ins?')">
<div id="formWrapper">
<h3>Check In Report</h3>
<div class="textInput">
<fieldset>
<label for="date">Display Report Since: </label>                
<input type="date" id = "displayDate" style="cursor:pointer;" /><br>
</fieldset>
</div>          
<div class="subInput">
<fieldset>
<input type="reset" value="Clear" name="clearB" style="width: 90px;cursor:pointer;">
<input type="submit" value="Display" name="submitB" style="width: 90px;cursor:pointer;">
</fieldset>
</div></div></form></div> <!-- formWrapper --></div> <!-- mainContainer -->
</div> <!-- Wrapper -->
<div id="userMenu">
<?php include("./userMenu.php")?>
</div> <!-- userMenu -->
</div> <!-- Screen -->
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried so many combinations, tried PhP functions and echo in the value tag inside the input, tried the

```
onload ="defaultDate()"
```

inside the  tag, but no matter what I do, I keep getting nothing, just the normal dd/mm/yyyy in the date box.

I would appreciate any help, I have looked into all the answers given before to similar problems and none of them actually works.

Thank you.

Comment: In which date format you are trying to display the date?

Comment: I want the date in the same format as the type="date" in html, as in dd/mm/yyyy. When I load the page, instead of getting the default dd/mm/yyyy you would normally get on the calendar picker, i want it to display the current date by default.

Comment: By the way, this is inside a <form>, not that I believe that would make a difference, but just in case, I'd rather be thorough in my question so I don't waste anybody's time.

Comment: Never trust a client's date. Always supply a date from the server, since JS can always be spoofed. if in php, you can use the [date](http://il1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to echo the date in the format you desire.

Comment: It's a simple internal network for project purposes, security is not an issue here, but thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1):

If you havn't particular needs, you should launch the function when the page loads (with window.onload).
I've also edited a bit your function to show the date in the dd/mm/yyyy format. Here's the code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    defaultDate()
};

function defaultDate()
{
var today = new Date();
document.getElementById("displayDate").value = [today.getDate(), today.getMonth()+1, .getFullYear()].join('/');
}
```

Comment: Please explain how you arrived at your answer not just give it,

Comment: awesome, this way it's answer to somone with a different but similar problem

Comment: Tried it, same again, nothing happening. Thank you for taking your time to try and answer.

Answer (score 0):

The scripts in the head are executed before the DOM is ready therefore your displayDate doesn't exist.

You have two choices:
- Make your code wait for the DOM to be ready
- Put your script at the bottom of the page (Simpler but uglier)

Comment: Tried that, same thing over and over, I'm starting to wonder if I have a mistake somewhere else, I will look deeper into the matter and come back with an update, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d= new Date();
var year= d.getFullYear();
var month= d.getMonth();
var date=d.getDate();
var day= d.getDay();
var h= leftPad(d.getHours(), 2);
var m= leftPad(d.getMinutes(), 2);
var s= leftPad(d.getSeconds(), 2);
var time= (h%12==0?"12":h%12) + ":" + m + ":" + s + (h>11?" PM":" AM");
$("#date-time").html("Today is "+ mos[month] + " " + date + ", " + year + " (" + days[day] +")  + time);
```